# How to collect Excel.Application objects opened in a system?

Tags: excel, vba

I found the following code which is based on **GetRunningObjectTable** - *WinAPI* function.It collects all excel application objects into *var* array.
The problem that i am having in this code is that when i press run, it says : "CollectROT.dll" cannot be found.Also I could not find the library for ROT(Running Object Table).

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetRunningExcelApps Lib "CollectROT.dll" (ByRef result As Variant) As Long
Public Const dllname As String = "CollectROT.dll"
Public glbApp As Application

Public Function GetExcelAppCollection() As Variant
Dim var As Variant
Dim appcalc As Long
Dim app As Application

ChDir (ThisWorkbook.Path)

appcalc = GetRunningExcelApps(var)
If appcalc > 0 Then
GetExcelAppCollection = var
Else
GetExcelAppCollection = Empty
End If
Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: I am afraid that you need  "CollectROT.dll" which has been developed from somebody. GetRunningExcelApps it looks to not be an ordinary API like the ones existing in "USER32", "ole32" etc. libraries... But what you need can be obtained using ordinary APIs. I have a piece of code dealing with all Excel open sessions. I found it on the internet some time before. I will adapting it in order to prepare an answer able to return in such a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Please, copy the next code on top of a standard module (in the declarations area). It is designed to work in both (32 - 64 bit) versions:

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "USER32" Alias _
            "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, _
            ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
            ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function IIDFromString Lib "ole32" _
            (ByVal lpsz As LongPtr, ByRef lpiid As GUID) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" _
            (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal dwId As LongPtr, ByRef riid As GUID, _
            ByRef ppvObject As Object) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
            (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
             ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function IIDFromString Lib "ole32" _
            (ByVal lpsz As Long, ByRef lpiid As GUID) As Long
    Private Declare Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" _
            (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal dwId As Long, ByRef riid As GUID, _
             ByRef ppvObject As Object) As Long
#End If

Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(7) As Byte
End Type
Private Const S_OK As Long = &H0
Private Const IID_IDispatch As String = "{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
Private Const OBJID_NATIVEOM As Long = &HFFFFFFF0
```

2. Please, copy the next code in the same standard module. This should be the function doing what (I understood) you need:

```
Function GetExcelAppCollection() As Variant
   Dim dict As Object, i As Long
    #If VBA7 Then
        Dim hWinXL As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim hWinXL As Long
    #End If
    Dim xlApp As Object 'Excel.Application

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    hWinXL = FindWindowEx(0&, 0&, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
    While hWinXL > 0
        i = i + 1
        If GetXLapp(hWinXL, xlApp) Then
            If Not dict.Exists(xlApp.hWnd) Then
                dict.Add xlApp.hWnd, xlApp
            End If
        End If
        hWinXL = FindWindowEx(0, hWinXL, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
    Wend
     GetExcelAppCollection = dict.Items
End Function
```

3. Copy the next function (called by the above one) in the same module:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Function GetXLapp(hWinXL As LongPtr, xlApp As Object) As Boolean
    Dim hWinDesk As LongPtr, hWin7 As LongPtr
#Else
    Function GetXLapp(hWinXL As Long, xlApp As Object) As Boolean
    Dim hWinDesk As Long, hWin7 As Long
#End If

Dim obj As Object
Dim iid As GUID
    
    Call IIDFromString(StrPtr(IID_IDispatch), iid)
    hWinDesk = FindWindowEx(hWinXL, 0&, "XLDESK", vbNullString)
    hWin7 = FindWindowEx(hWinDesk, 0&, "EXCEL7", vbNullString)
    If AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hWin7, OBJID_NATIVEOM, iid, obj) = S_OK Then
        Set xlApp = obj.Application
        GetXLapp = True
    End If
End Function
```

3. It can be tested using the next test `Sub`:

```
Sub testGetExAppColl()
   Dim arr As Variant
   arr = GetExcelAppCollection
   Debug.Print arr(0).Workbooks(1).Name, arr(UBound(arr)).Workbooks.count
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback. The code is not so complicated as it can be considered at the first glance... I can simplify it for being used only in 64 bit environment, but I do not think that this can really be an issue.

If something not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask, please.

***Edited:***

The next function returns all open workbooks (as objects) in a collection. It is similar to the one returning Excel application objects, but it dig a little deeper, extracting all open documents:

```
Function GetAllWorkbooks() As Collection
    Dim i As Long 
    #If VBA7 Then
        Dim hWinXL As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim hWinXL As Long
    #End If
    Dim xlApp As Object 'Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Object  ' Excel.Workbook
    Dim dict, k, Col As New Collection
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    hWinXL = FindWindowEx(0&, 0&, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
    While hWinXL > 0
        i = i + 1
        If GetXLapp(hWinXL, xlApp) Then
            If Not dict.Exists(xlApp.hWnd) Then
                dict.Add xlApp.hWnd, xlApp
                For Each wb In xlApp.Workbooks
                    Col.Add wb
                Next
            End If
        End If
        hWinXL = FindWindowEx(0, hWinXL, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
    Wend
    Set GetAllWorkbooks = Col
End Function
```

In order to test it, you can use the next `Sub`:

```
Sub EnumAllOpenWorkbooks()
    Dim Col As Collection, wb As Workbook
    
    Set Col = GetAllWorkbooks()
    For Each wb In Col
        'you can find the one you need
        Debug.Print wb.Name & ":" & _
           IIf(wb.Application.hWnd = Application.hWnd, _
                 "In this instance", "In another instance")
    Next wb
End Sub
```

Comment: Tanks, @Zac! I used something similar and it was easy to create a function doing what (I understand) he needs...

Comment: Yes, excellent answer and upvoted as well, but on the other hand it really does only answer the requirement of the OP. This will help the OP in his needs but it will probaly not increase his understanding of the underlying problem. Anyway, excellent answer.

Comment: @Storax: Thanks! I tried answering his question, indeed... What do you think it would be good to do besides that? To comment the code lines? I had that in mind, but I did not want threatening by showing a bushy one. I can also post a function returning all open workbooks in those Excel open sessions, but it is also a matter of something looking very complicated... Anyhow, it will be a good idea edit the answer in order to also suggest him to ask if something not clear enough. Thanks again!

Comment: @FaneDuru: Difficult question but by using code like yours the OP will never undertand what is wrong with his code in the first place although you explained that to the OP in your comment. So, maybe the correct answer to the question would have been your comment which, of course, is not really satisfying.

Comment: @Storax problem with this kind of solution is that if you know it, it's easy to understand. On the other hand, if you don't understand or have knowledge of using external API's, it is tricky to explain (although the concept is relatively  simple). I do get your point but the trick is to give enough but not too much otherwise it feels too complicated

Comment: @Storax: I would like to believe that, correlating my comment with my answer, he should be able to understand what is wrong with his code. But I cannot swear... If he will send some feedback we can clarify this issue, too, I think. If not, maybe somebody else will find it useful... :)  It was difficult to choose between writing a very detailed answer, well commented and something to be used, instead of what he was trying to accomplish... At least, what I could understand about it.

Comment: @FaneDuru It solved my issue but the code is little complicated to understand as i'm just starting with API.I'll go through it.Thanks !!

Comment: @Pramod Pandit: Glad I could help! If you need further assistance to understand something, or parts which are not clear enough for you, do not hesitate to ask, please!

Comment: @Pramod Pandit: If interested, I can also paste a function to return all open workbooks **from all open Excel sessions**. At least to study it... And besides all that, there is a different way to identify the session if you need a specific open workbook and you know its full name. Or in case that another application creates a new session (many times hidden) and drops an unsaved workbook, something like "Book1, 2, 3 ...`. It is possible to also get the session keeping them. Of course, if not workbook is open in many sessions (even read only), or many "Book1" type are open in different sessions

Comment: @FaneDuru Yeah,please do provide function to return all open workbooks/specific workbook and to get hidden workbook.Also does the hidden workbook means an application creates temporary excel file then deletes it after closing the application ? These will definitely help me to understand API further.Also,i noticed if i open multiple workbooks at once call the function then only *active* workbooks are shown and rest ignored.For eg: `arr(1).Workbooks(1).SaveAs "TESTS", , "1"` This code will only call and save active workbook and rest opened workbooks are ignored.

Comment: @Pramod Pandit: Edited the answer and added the function in discussion. But it was not about the 'hidden workbooks'... It was about the hidden Excel sessions. I mean the not visible once. If you create a new Excel session and you do not make it `Visible`, it is `Hidden`. Then, using `Workbooks(1)` this means referring to the first workbook. In order to refer any of the respective session open workbooks you need to iterate between them and choose the one you want. Maybe, it will be good to also give you an example, but this is somehow against the community rules...

Comment: @Pramod Pandit: I meant, we here answer questions helping people to adapt and understand their code, in order to make it more efficient. And help people to learn. When an answer becomes enciclopedic, it loses its purpose... I mean, if you need further and deeper treatment on the issue, you can make some reference to this thread and ask whatever you need...

Comment: @FaneDuru Ok ,will do provide reference to this thread if needed.Can you provide test `sub` to call the function ? `arr = GetAllWorkbooks` seems to throw an error.

Comment: @Pramod Pandit: Sorry... I thought it would be easy to test it looking to the function return declaration. The return should be a `Collection`. But I was wrong, since you look to be a beginner. Adapted the code with such a testing `Sub`. Please, confirm that it works as you need.

Comment: @FaneDuru It works as i expected.Thank you for your help !!

Comment: @Pramod Pandit: Glad I could help! The key is to go through all code lines and **try understanding**. Look on the internet and imagine ways to test your understanding. The ways you discover by yourself will be well fixed in your mind. But, if you will have problems in understanding, do not hesitate to ask. It is also a way of learning, but it is strictly necessary to **completely understand** the answers you receive...

Answer (score 0):

.Net has his own "api-dll" to manage proccess.

Try that and tell me if is useful for you.

```
For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses
    If String.compare(p.ProcessName, "excel",true) = 0 Then
        'Do stuff
        msgbox("hi im a excel process")
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This is not a matter of (only) finding the process! A COM object must be returned, for each running Excel session... You must be able to use them, not only seeing that they exist.